# Html/Javascript/bootstrap: Opening a different part of the website from a button inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

Basically all I'm looking to do is to be able to open up a different section of the website from a button in my modal. I need the modal to be able to link to another .html page I've built for the website. I'm pretty new to bootstrap, so it's tripping me up a bit.

Here's the code from the modal.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-theme" data-dismiss="modal">Not interested</a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-theme" data-toggle="modal" id="cobol">See more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the "See more" button to link to a new html template.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "different section of the website from a button in my modal", you mean you want to expand it below?

Answer (score 0):

just use the `href`

```
<a href="another.html" type="button" class="btn btn-theme">See more</a>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I tried using href before, but it was just doing nothing when I linked the page and clicked on the button. It would just sit there on the modal. So, I thought there was something I was missing. I finally figured it out though!